# How to convert string abcabc to abc in C#

Tags: c#, string

How to convert string like

> "abcabc"

to

> "abc"

Here is what want to achieve

> ANDSQLP47ANDSQLP47\CTOPROD8R2

to

> ANDSQLP47\CTOPROD8R2

Comment: show some code. what did you try? and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I don't understand why so many down votes?

Comment: @X-TECH because it's unclear and the user show no search effort?

Comment: @Thomas that cants explain 6 downvotes.i think some people get blind when they see question is downvoted and they just down vote.

Comment: this is what i tried. I am a newbie and just wanted help                                                                             data = String.Join(" ", data.Split(' ').Distinct());

Comment: It is not affecting the result

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary and you think it's worth 3 up votes?

Comment: @Thomas it does not but i upvoted to say hey, this question does not deserve -6. so -3 in total better.

Comment: Wait a minute, you just posted a question that *produces* the wrong data - why don't you just fix the producer instead of trying to fix the results afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

You can use some Regex to find the repeating pattern and do the replacement:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)\1\\(\w+)");
var result = regex.Replace(@"ANDSQLP47ANDSQLP47\CTOPROD8R2", @"$1\$2");
//result: ANDSQLP47\CTOPROD8R2
```

Regex explanation:

```
(\w+) : Match sequence of characters (first capture group $1) 
\1 : Match same sequence of characters as first capture group
\\ : Match '\' character
(\w+) : Match sequence of characters (second capture group $2)
```

You can get more info about Regex [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit:**

To match a string with two repeated words, I would use the following Regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(\w+)\1$");
var result = regex.Replace(@"abcabc", @"$1");
//result: abc
```

^ and $ denote the start and end of the string, so that it matches only if the whole text is the repetition of two words.

Comment: I don't have knowledge of Regex can you provide me code where i can get my required result

Comment: The code is already there in my answer...

Comment: Ok thanks it worked and now I have one more thing what if there is no \ between string like convert simple abcabc to abc

Comment: Thank you very much and can we set length of string as well like if 4 words are repeating consecutively not 2 or 3 like ababab should not be coverted to ab